# Correct Usage of from

Tags: grammaticality

What does this sentence imply -

1. I have got a bit exhausted from doing all the house hold work .

According to my knowledge it should mean that I have got tired because I have been doing house hold work. Can from be used this way ?

Comment: In your example *from* means *because of*. Yes, that is one of the meanings of *from*.

Answer (score 2):

Oxford lists 11 subtly different definitions of "from". The one that applies here is:

> indicating a cause.
>   eg *a child suffering from asthma*.

So, in your example, doing housework is the cause of exhaustion.